# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTConvert react-native-payments

Tags: react-native, payment

I just Added the Package react-native-payments IOS Build is not working [image]

I tried to add Payment package and running into this issue IOS build is not working

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Package is not linked to your pods. With the pod config of my project, I manually added in the path within my podfile, [as well as added the library to xcode](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios). Go into the build settings of the `react-native-payments` pod, and change the ios deployment to what will work with your project (for me that was from ios 7 to ios 11). Next add `$(SRCROOT)/../../React` and `$(SRCROOT)/../../react-native/React` to the Header search paths of your target (accessible from Project Name > Targets > Build settings >Search Paths).

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to ios folder and run `pod deintegrate && pod install`